# how to list the classlist file with the absolute and relative path using LINUX command line?

Tags: linux

I have a question regarding LINUX command line that i don't really understand:

Run the following commands.

```
$ cd

$ mkdir hw1-test

$ cd hw1-test

$ls /class/home > classlist

$ cd
```

**what does the fourth command do?**

**Question:**

Show the ls command you ran with the absolute path.

Show the ls command you ran with the relative path.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The fourth command `ls /class/home > classlist` makes a list of all files in `/class/home` and stores it in `classlist` file.

Comment: thanks! but the question says to show the ls command. What are the two paths that lead to me to classlist file?

Comment: You want ls command to print realtive paths and absolute paths in file classlist right? @Catherine

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @minigeek yes, i am kind of confused with the relative paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4th command  lists out all the file in the directory to filename classlist in the same directory.

**What is an absolute path?**

An absolute path is defined as the specifying the location of a file or directory from the root directory(/). In other words we can say absolute path is a complete path from start of actual filesystem from / directory

**What is the relative path?**

Relative path is defined as path related to the present working directory(pwd). Suppose I am located in /var/log and I want to change directory to /var/log/kernel. I can use relative path concept to change directory to kernel.

**Examples :**

changing directory to /var/log/kernel by using relative path concept.

```
pwd
/var/log
cd kernel
```

Note: If you observe there is no / before kernel which indicates it’s a relative directory to present working directory.

Changing directory to /var/log/kernel using absolute path concept.

```
cd /var/log/kernel
```

Example 2: Present location is /abc/xyz, I am want to remove /abc/xyz/read/hello.txt file.

Using relative path:

```
rm read/hello.txt
```

Using absolute path:

```
rm /abc/xyz/read/hello.txt
```

**SO ANSWERS TO YOUR QUESTIONS ARE**

*Show the ls command you ran with the absolute path*

so absoulte path means full path.
Just open your terminal and you should know path of the directory you want to visit.
As you said in the question your path is `/class/home/` i.e class is in root folder and home is inside it and you want to list out files in it so type

```
ls /class/home/ > classlist
```

*Show the ls command you ran with the relative path*

so now for relative path you will have to ennter into the directory one before the actual directory of home i.e. class 
when you open your terminal you are in home directory by default i.e `/Username/home`

so type

```
 cd .. //it will take you back into class directory

if you want to check you can check it with `pwd`.
and it will show your present working directory.
```

do

```
ls  home/ >  classlist
```

Comment: this relative path does not work for me even if i am the directory where i created classlist

Comment: Did it help you now @ Catherine